# Is it possible to use C# (and C++) in a Javascript Metro app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to use C# and C++ in a JavaScript Metro app?

The app is a Javascript/HTML app, but I want to use some libraries that are available in C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can create a Windows Runtime Component in C# (and C++) and as long as the public types and members exposed by your component are Windows Runtime types, the WinRT projections to JavaScript will allow your HTML/JavaScript app to invoke methods within that component.

Here are a couple of references for more information:

[Creating Windows Runtime Components in C# and Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx)

[Creating Windows Runtime Components in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441569.aspx)

[Windows Runtime Components in a .NET World](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651570.aspx)